# passing $_POST["variable"] in a html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to pass a $_POST["variable"] in a html table but I cannot, how should I get it?
I show the code.

```
$number = $_POST["limit"];
$variable = $_POST["variable"];
//echo "numero " . $numero;
echo "variable " . $variable;


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City, Data, $variable FROM Net2 where Data BETWEEN '" . split($_POST["date6"]) ."' AND '" . split($_POST["date7"]) ."' order by TMax desc limit $number");
```

Here I create the table and I want to pass $variable, but I cannot...How?

```
echo "<div id= 'capatabla'>";
echo "<table  border='1'>
<thead>
<tr bgcolor= '#3399FF'> 
<th>City</th>
<th>$variable</th>
<th>Data</th>
</tr>
</thead>";


echo "<tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td >" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['$variable'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Data'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Your code raises a lot more questions. 1. How are you setting your `$_POST[]` values? 2. In what order is this getting executed? 3. Did you make a connection to your database? Plus you're seeting yourself up for SQL injection by doing this: ...`where Data BETWEEN '" . split($_POST["date6"]) .`...

Comment: <th>".$variable."</th> should be to view variable

Comment: "I want to... but I cannot" is to vague. What is happening. Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: look at sanitizing and validating your post variables before they touch your database

Comment: Yes I did a connection to my database. These variables come from another script, where I use <form action="consultingvariables.php" method="POST">   Now, with your help it runs!!!! Big help

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish, you can try to use an alias on the mysql query. It might fix it:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City, Data, $variable as variable_test FROM Net2 where Data BETWEEN '" . split($_POST["date6"]) ."' AND '" . split($_POST["date7"]) ."' order by TMax desc limit $number");
```

An the while should look like:

```
echo "<tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td >" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['variable_test'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Data'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Using an alias now it runs! It is solved!